# Create Google Team Drive with Perl module LWP::Authen::OAuth2

Tags: json, perl, lwp

I'm trying to use Perl with LWP::Authen::OAuth2 to perform google team drive creation. Understand to create google team drive using google Drive API, it requires 1 param to be posted that is `requestId` and another json body `name` (reference: https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/teamdrives/create)

However, I keep getting the error code 400 and error message saying

> The Team Drive name must be provided, not empty, and not entirely whitespace.

which indicate the json body of `name` is not posted correctly.

Below is my code:

```
# Go get the auth tokens
$oauth2->request_tokens(code => $code);

my $requestID = "randomrequestID";
my $json = '{"name": "anyteamdrivename"}';

my $resp = $oauth2->post("https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/teamdrives?requestId=$requestID, Content-Type => application/json, Content => $json");


my $data = decode_json($resp->content());
use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper $data;
```

Appreciate if someone with Perl knowledge will be able to shade some light.

Comment: You are not correclty passing the parameters: `"https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/teamdrives?requestId=$requestID, Content-Type => application/json, Content => $json"` - move everything starting from `Content-Type` out of the string.

Comment: i just change it to `my $resp = $oauth2->post("https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/teamdrives?requestId=$requestID", "Content-Type => application/json", "Content => $json");` but im still getting the same error code and message

Comment: Yes, because you're still passing the parameters wrong. See the documentation of `LWP::UserAgent` on `->post`: https://metacpan.org/pod/LWP::UserAgent . You need `'Content-Type' => 'application/json', 'Content' => $json)` .

Comment: oh my, you are right Corion. Such a simple yet accurate answer from you. I just corrected them and it works, thanks Corion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not correctly passing the parameters in your call to `->post`:

```
my $resp = $oauth2->post("https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/teamdrives?requestId=$requestID, Content-Type => application/json, Content => $json");
```

Move everything starting from Content-Type out of the string:

```
my $resp = $oauth2->post(
    "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/teamdrives?requestId=$requestID",
    "Content-Type" => "application/json",
    "Content" => $json
);
```

See also the documentation of [LWP::UserAgent](https://metacpan.org/pod/LWP::UserAgent) on the `->post` method.